Translation of "Nulla dies sine linea" into English within Context Given
A quote of St. Philip Neri:

Nulla dies sine linea: Do not let a day pass without doing some good during it.

QUESTION: How may "Nulla dies sine linea" be translated here? (I would think it translates into: "No day without a line"---but that doesn't seem to make much sense when we look at the provided English after the semicolon.) See: January 2 here

Did you search for the phrase online? It seems to have its own Wikipedia article.

@JoonasIlmavirta Thank you very much for the link. I did not expect the phrase to have its own article. Thanks again.

You're correct about the literal meaning! But this is an idiom, that doesn't mean quite the same thing as the literal combination of words. Here's Pliny's explanation of where the idiom comes from, involving the famous painter Apelles of Kos.

Apellī fuit aliōquī perpetua cōnsuētūdō numquam tam occupātum diem agendī, ut nōn līneam dūcendō exercēret artem, quod ab eō in prōverbium vēnit.
It was a regular custom of Apelles's to never let a workday be so busy that he couldn't practice his art by drawing [at least one] line, which has become a proverb because of him.

In other words, Apelles wouldn't let a day go by without doing some little bit of his art, like drawing a single outline. But for someone who's not a painter, the linea could be a metaphor for something else, like a musician playing a single scale, or an author writing a single sentence. The idea is to practice every day, even if it's a seemingly insignificant amount, because over time it will add up, and committing to one line is easier than committing to an hour of practice or whatnot.
